# Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Promise<Loaded<Post, never> | null>'

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql

I'm doing Ben Awad's YouTube course and I have an issue with the update mutation in the app.

A record (`Post`) is loaded from the database, and then modified according to provided data (ID and new title). But when I fetch that record, it seems to be of a different type, not ready to be easily modified and loaded back into the DB.

Here's an update mutation:

```
@Mutation(() => Post, { nullable: true })
    async updatePost(
        @Arg("_id") _id: number,
        @Arg("title", () => String, { nullable: true }) title: string,
        @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
    ): Promise<Post | null> {
        // Fetch post
        const post = em.findOne(Post, { _id });
        // If unable to find post
        if (!post) {
            return null;
        }
        if (typeof title !== "undefined") {
            post.title = title;
            await em.persistAndFlush(post);
        }
        return post;
    }
```

The problem is, VS Code doesn't like `title` in `post.title`, and I get the following message:

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Promise<Loaded<Post, never> | null>'.ts(2339)
```

I'm totally new to TypeScript so I don't know the workaround. I'm guessing the reason is that `Post<>` is "wrapped" in `Loaded<>`. The issue must be caused by version differences—everything works fined in Ben's 2020 video.

Any help/explanation would be much appreciated!

I tried looking how to "unwrap" and reach the object, but I felt asking it here would be faster :p

Comment: "*I'm guessing the reason is that `Post<>` is "wrapped" in `Loaded<>`*" - no. Or: maybe. But the primary issue is that it's wrapped in a `Promise`, since you forgot to `await` the `em.findOne` call.

Comment: You can either [answer it yourself](/help/self-answer) or just delete it if you found a solution

Comment: @Bergi yes, but I had the impression that answering your own questions was frowned upon :,)

Comment: No, no, it's totally fine if you believe that the answer will help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the post variable as you are using findOne

```
const post = await em.findOne(Post, { _id });
```

these have solved my bug and would solve yours too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).